# How can I update all records in 1 request using parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to set a particular column to some value for all users, how do I achieve that?

Example, set the 'changed' column to 'true' for all users. Any cheap way to do it?

Comment: I think it only possible in cloud (iterate through all rows and update). It is cheap, and when getting used to it, it becomes easy :)

Comment: Hi, cloud code is not the cheap way, as huge amount of rows (like a million), will definitely slow and time out. Parse.com calculate the cost by the amount of "save" operation, with 1 million rows, it will have 1 million operations, which finished up the free quota. Using batch can save some time, but still not smart enough. I can pay for more, but there should be some smarter way, like how SQL do it: UPDATE table SET col1 = true;

Comment: I thought by cheap you meant: cheap by time. As far as I know there is no way to do this, but you can make a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to do it cheaply, I don't think that you can change a huge amount of data without incurring a lot of api calls.

Perhaps, export your data as a JSON file

(they will email you the JSON)

[image]

Write a short script to parse the JSON and change the value you want

Import Your document back

[image]

Comment: Not the smartest way, but acceptable. Too bad my table is live, so I can't use this approach. I changed my structure to fulfill my need. I still mark it as answer, since this might be useful for other people.